# Как поместить текст на скрипт который помещен на этот текст?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объект и скрипт. Скрипт прекреплен к этому же объекту. Нужно поместить этот объект типа Text в скрипт(предположим под переменной Txt).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Script:MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Txt;

    void Start() {
        Txt = ...;
    }
}
```

Такой код только вмесио троеточия нужен этот объект.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не нужно делать, просто обращайтесь к встроенному в скрипт полю `gameObject`.

Например

```
gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

или

```
gameObject.Destroy();
```

Это и есть тот самый объект, который вам нужен.

Comment: Окей спаибо, но что если объект имеет тип Text?

Comment: @Chelovek дополните вопрос, у вас там нет никаких `Text`. А так в любой строчке кода можно сделать каст `var text = gameObject as Text;`. Поле в скрипте для этого не требуется.

Comment: Извините я просто не знал что это будет отличатся сейчас дополню